# Using c++ typedef/using type alias

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

I am reading C++ primer book and completely don't understand one line:

```
 using int_array = int[4]; 
 typedef int int_array[4]; // This line
 for (int_array *p = ia; p != ia + 3; ++p) {
      for (int *q = *p; q != *p + 4; ++q)
          cout << *q << ' '; cout << endl;
 }
```

Ok `typedef` is same as `using`. Does it mean `int[4][4]` is now `int` and how to understand that? And what type is `int_array` in `for` loop?

Thanks

Comment: Upvote for "reading c++ primer book"

Comment: Both the `using` line and the `typedef` line do the same thing

Comment: And by the way the new syntax works with template... I think it was introduce for that purpose.

Comment: @plats1: Vote on the question not on what book the OP is reading

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: That comment sounds to me not an assessment of *which* book, but a reward for going to the trouble of reading any book instead of treating SO like a tutorial.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Right, and "rewards" for reading a book are not what the voting system is for! Voting is to produce a score representing the perceived quality of the post. But you do already know that I am sure.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It could fall under "This question shows research effort" which is an upvote reason.  I won't upvote a question for that, but I have no beef with someone who chooses to.

Answer (score 24):

### TL;DR

Both are doing the exact same thing: Defining `int_array` as an alias of an array of 4 `int`s

### Making Sense of the Syntax

`using` has a nice A = B notation that is generally much easier to understand.

```
using alias = type;
```

`typedef`'s notation is not quite backward. For a simple `typedef`

```
typedef type alias;
```

but more complicated `typedef`s tend to sprawl. I suspect the syntax was modeled after how one would define a variable, but I can't find where I packed my copy of the old K&R C programming book and can't look that up at the moment.

```
int int_array[4];
```

would define `int_array` to be an array of 4 `int`s. Slapping `typedef` on the front

```
typedef int int_array[4];
```

makes `int_array` a type alias instead of a variable.

Another example,

```
int * intp;
```

Defines `intp` to be a pointer to an `int`.

```
typedef int * intp;
```

Defines `intp` to be an alias to the type pointer to an `int`.

This gets ugly with more complicated data types as the name of the `typedef`ed alias may be buried somewhere in the middle of the definition. A `typedef`ed function pointer for example:

```
typedef void (*funcp)(param_t param1, param_t param2, ...);
```

vs using

```
using funcp = void (*)(param_t param1, param_t param2, ...);
```

### Making a 2D Array

If you want a 2D array you could

```
using int_array2D = int[4][4];
```

or you could define an array of int_array

```
using int_array2D = int_array[4];
```

And of course that means you can

```
using int_array3D = int_array2D[4];
```

and keep on going until the cows come home or you've packed on so many dimensions that [The Doctor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VkcHgI_TIYQ)'s brain melts.

Comment: That does make sense of the `typedef` syntax - which makes it easier to keep the syntax in my head rather than going "I'm just going to use `using`".

Answer (score 6):

## This line does nothing as it is redundant

The lines

```
using int_array = int[4];
```

and

```
typedef int int_array[4];
```

do the same thing. See reference for [using](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) and [typedef](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef). You can leave one or the other out and the behaviour is the same. It is not an error to have two different declarations, as they are not conflicting (they do the exact same thing).

The first way of doing it (using the `using` keyword) was introduced with C++11 and is in my opinion easier to read, so I prefer it over the typedef version.

Answer (score 1):

Both type aliases are the same:

---

[Type alias, alias template (since C++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):
Type alias is a name that refers to a previously defined type (similar to [typedef](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef)):

```
using identifier attr(optional) = type-id ;
```

---

so you may use:

```
typedef int int_array[4];
```

or  you may just use (it is the same as above):

```
using int_array = int[4];
```

When you need to address the memory with `4*sizeof(int)` steps, e.g. if the system `int` size is 4 bytes, then the memory step size is 4*4=16 bytes. even you may use `int_array *p;` in this case `++p` advances `p` by one memory step e.g. 16 bytes.
see:

---

1- working sample with `using int_array = int[4];`:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int ia[3][4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

    // a range for to manage the iteration
    // use type alias
    using int_array = int[4];
    for (int_array& p : ia)
        for (int q : p)
            cout << q << " ";
    cout << endl;

    // ordinary for loop using subscripts
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
            cout << ia[i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    // using pointers.
    // use type alias
    for (int_array* p = ia; p != ia + 3; ++p)
        for (int *q = *p; q != *p + 4; ++q)
            cout << *q << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output 1:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

---

2- working sample using `typedef int int_array[4];`:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int ia[3][4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

    // a range for to manage the iteration
    // use type alias
    typedef int int_array[4];
    for (int_array& p : ia)
        for (int q : p)
            cout << q << " ";
    cout << endl;

    // ordinary for loop using subscripts
    for (size_t i = 0; i != 3; ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
            cout << ia[i][j] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    // using pointers.
    // use type alias
    for (int_array* p = ia; p != ia + 3; ++p)
        for (int *q = *p; q != *p + 4; ++q)
            cout << *q << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output 2(same):

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Ref: https://github.com/Mooophy/Cpp-Primer/blob/master/ch03/ex3_44.cpp
Note: use `-std=c++11` for compile/link.